# how to disable select field when a input element is active?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i disable the selectfield when inputfield is active. When i submit the form i need to send only 1 parameter with the form, select or input.
Mayby somebody have an idea.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <body>
      <script>
   var selectData = {

  "sel1":{
     
    "100":"select100", //select data
  "101":"select101",//select data
   "102":"select102",//select data
    "103":"select103",//select data
     "104":"select104",//select data
      "":"",
 
  },
   "sel2":{
     
  "201":"select201", // select data
    "202":"select202",
   "203":"select203",
    "204":"select204",
     "205":"select205"
 
  },
   "sel3":{
     
   "301":"select301",
     "302":"select302",
   "303":"select303",
    "304":"select304",
     "305":"select305"
 
 
  }
  };
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $(document).on('click', '.specialLink', function(event) {

        var radio2 = document.getElementById('radio2');
        if (radio2.checked == false) {
          radio2.checked = true;
          toggleRadio();
        }

        event.preventDefault();
        var b = $(this),
          buttonId = b.attr('id'),
          selectSet = selectData[buttonId],
          selectField = $('#specialLink');
        selectField.empty();
        if (selectSet) {
          $.each(selectSet, function(k, v) {
            selectField.append($('<option>', {
              value: k,
              text: v
            }));
          });
        }
        return false;
      });
    });
    </script>
      
    <li><a href="#" id="sel1" class="specialLink">Selectlist1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" id="sel2" class="specialLink">Selectlist2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="sel3" class="specialLink">Selectlist3</a></li>
    
    
        <form method="post" name="multiform" id="form8" action="/search" onchange="toggleRadio();">
            <label for="radio1">INPUT Text</label>
            <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="select" checked />
            <label for="radio2">SELECT from</label>
            <input id="radio2" name="select" type="radio" />
            <label id="textLabel" for="textin">Formular
                <input id="textin" name="fromtext" type="text" placeholder="test1" />
            </label>
            <label id="selectLabel" for="specialLink">Items
                <select name="fromlist" id="specialLink">
                  <option selected> choose a selectlist first</option>
                
                </select>
            </label>
            <input value="Search"  type="submit">  
        </form>
        <script>
function toggleRadio() { // will activate when the form will change.
    var radio1 = document.getElementById('radio1'); // radio 1
    var radio2 = document.getElementById('radio2'); // radio 2
    if (radio1.checked == true) { // if the first checked display input and hide select
        document.getElementById('textLabel').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('selectLabel').style.display = 'none';
       
    }
    else { // because i got only 2 option i don't have to use another condition
        document.getElementById('textLabel').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('selectLabel').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('textin').value = ''; // clear input
    }
}
toggleRadio(); // call the function
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can i disable the selectfield when inputfield is active. When i submit the form i need to send only 1 parameter with the form, select or input.
Mayby somebody have an idea.

Comment: Could you clarify what are selectfield and inputfield ?

Comment: I need to disable the selectlabel when the textlabel is active and i submit the form. .

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Thank you Quentin for your answer. Now I send a empty value with the disable field. That solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the client side, you can empty the field value of select when input is chosen and vice versa.
At the server side, you can use a custom variable to detect which is the actual input (i.e. input or select) and use a simple if-else statement to for processing

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery function `$(awesomeObject).prop();` in a function like this:

```
if ($("#radio1").checked == true) {
    $("#specialLink").prop("disabled", true);
}
```

When an input has the property disabled to True it will stop going to the server.

See here: http://api.jquery.com/prop/